# using Dirichlet transforms to show infinity of primes

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to understand the following lemma and its proof. The lemma and proof are on page 2 of this pdf: http://www.ias.ac.in/resonance/March2012/p284-290.pdf

Basically, I want to know their reasoning of switching sums? Why go over $n$ first, but then go over $r$ after and what is "r" anyways.

Also I am confused about they can apply the formula for geometric series.

And my final question is how does this (combined with the Möbius formula) imply infinitude of primes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, probably a typo.. I think, this should be correct:

$$F(z)=\sum_{r\ge 1} \hat f(r)\, z^r=\sum_{r\ge 1}\sum_{d|r}f(d)\,z^r=\sum_{d\ge 1}\sum_{n\ge 1}f(d)z^{nd}=\sum_df(d)\cdot \frac{z^d}{1-z^d}\,.$$

**Update:** In the  [finalized version](http://pollack.uga.edu/infprimes-final.pdf)  (which you mentioned only in a comment), these formulas are all correct, and the conclusion for having infinitely many primes follows:

Consider the convolution unit: $\hat u(1)=1$ and $\hat u(n)=0$ if $n>1$, with that, by the inversion formula, we have
$$u(n)=\sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d)\,\hat u(d)=\mu(n)\,.$$
Now the support of $\hat u$ is $\{1\}$, finite, so, by the lemma the support of $u=\mu$ must be infinite. However, if we had only finitely many primes, there would be only finitely many square-free numbers (all the products of distinct primes), so $\mu$ would be of finite support, a contradiction.

Comment: Could you share why the infinitude of primes follow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems there are typos in the Lemma.  The reasoning for switching the sums is that the series for $F(z)$ is absolutely convergent.  The idea is you want to sum over $rd = n$, but the last equation line in the Lemma is not written correctly.

I do not see how the infinitude of the primes follows from the fact that $\mu$ has infinite support.

Comment: The main paper is here, so maybe this can help you? http://math.uga.edu/~pollack/infprimes-final.pdf